Asset Validation Failed: Invalid Signature for BillDeskSDK in Flutter iOS App?
I have implemented the BillDeskSDK in my Flutter app, and it works fine on all iOS devices when I run it from Xcode. However, when I try to deploy the app to the App Store or TestFlight, I encounter the following issue:
I have been struggling with this issue for two days and have tried all possible solutions available on the internet, but nothing has helped. Any assistance would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Invalid Signature. Code object is not signed at all. The file at path
“Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/flutter_assets/packages/billDeskSDK/files/sdk_info.sh”
is not properly signed. Make sure you have signed your application
with a distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a
development certificate. Verify that the code signing settings in
Xcode are correct at the target level (which override any values at
the project level). Additionally, make sure the bundle you are
uploading was built using a Release target in Xcode, not a Simulator
target. If you are certain your code signing settings are correct,
choose “Clean All” in Xcode, delete the “build” directory in the
Finder, and rebuild your release target. For more information, please
consult https://developer.apple.com/support/code-signing. (ID:
9dbe3870-5df5-467d-b957-676cbb09edef)


